# Performance issue in Getting report using gridview from tables and view in SQL server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview, ssrs-2008

I have a database which has some table and every one of them has at least 100000 records.
I need to show reports of these data to admin of asp site so I have used views to join these table to get my required info to show. but the problem is when I run the page although it should show just 10 records for first page and other records can be lazy, it become time out because it takes so long time to make view and show in gridview.
Is there any way to handle this problem?
for example If I can make these joins for view when sql server is idle it will improve performance issue. But I don't know is it possible or not

Comment: Yes, there are ways. If you'd like to know what they are, please say more about what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi how about using paging and loading data on request in gridview  i mean here is an example hope this might help you:

[Loading data on request and paging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11397/A-sorting-and-paging-DataGrid-loading-data-on-dema)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use custom paging in you sql query